# A package for classes and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've built a framework that primarily provides automated Ajax and a way to emulate classes.  I've pasted the framework below and I hope it is well-commented.

`klass()` and `machine()` are the interesting methods.

I've also posted some application code so you have some idea of how it used.

I'm looking for general feedback on logic and organization.

I'm not looking to add any other features or increase the scope for now.  If anything, I need to make it smaller.

**Library**

```
/*******************************************************************************
** FRAME
**   manageGlobal - manages the single global variable that FRAME uses
**   time - basic timer
**   getDomElements - pull elements from the DOM
**   getLibElements - creates library elements ( change name )
**   initByProperty - execute class methods by property
**   klass - emulates a class system
**   machine - runs ajax on the classes among other things
**   definePipe - defines the model data for the entire application
**   makePipe - makes the model data for a single Ajax call
*******************************************************************************/

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var $A,
        $P = {},
        $R = {};
    $P.last = {};
    $R.Classes = {};
    $R.packet_hold = {};

    // requires utility and comms module
    (function manageGlobal() {
        if (window.$A && window.$A.pack && window.$A.pack.utility &&
                window.$A.pack.comms) {
            $A = window.$A;
            $A.pack.frame = true;
        } else {
            throw "frame requires utility and comms module";
        }
    }());

    // used to time performance by machine()
    $R.time = (function () {
        var measurements = [];
        return function (control) {
            var index,
                intervals = [],
                time_current = new Date().getTime();
            if (control === 'start') {
                measurements = [];
                measurements.push(time_current);
                return;
            }
            if (control !== 'finish') {
                measurements.push(time_current);
                return;
            }
            if (control === 'finish') {
                measurements.push(time_current);
                index = measurements.length;
                while (index) {
                    index -= 1;
                    intervals[index - 1] = (measurements[index] -
                            measurements[index - 1]) + 'ms';
                }
                return intervals;
            }
        };
    }());

    // get dom elements for each module
    $P.getDomElements = function (el_hold) {
        var list;

        // iterate through each module
        $A.someKey($R.Classes, function (val) {
            list = val[el_hold];
            if (list) {

                // iterate through each module's el_hold properties
                $A.someKey(list, function (val, key) {

                    // replace the id w/ an element reference
                    list[key] = $A.el(val);
                });
            }
        });
    };

    // get library elements for each module
    $P.getLibElements = function (lib_hold, lib_global) {
        var list;

        // iterate through each module
        $A.someKey($R.Classes, function (val) {
            list = val[lib_hold];
            if (list) {

                // iterate through the module's l_hold properties
                $A.someKey(list, function (val, key) {
                    list[key] = lib_global(val);
                });
            }
        });
    };

    // initialize each module by property
    $P.initByProperty = function (prop) {

        // iterate through each module
        $A.someKey($R.Classes, function (val) {

            // if the property exists execute it
            if (val[prop]) {
                val[prop]();
            }
        });
    };

    $P.klass = function (obj, config_module) {

        // log the class
        $R.Classes[obj.Name] = obj;

        // all properties are private and static ( there is no access )
        if (!config_module) {
            return undefined;
        }

        // all properties are public and static ( there is access, no instance )
        if (config_module === true) {
            return obj;
        }

        // constructor based, all properties are public and static/instance
        if (config_module === 'constructor') {
            var object_public;

            // retrieve the constructor
            if (obj.constructor) {
                object_public = obj.constructor;
                delete obj.constructor;
            }

            // add methods and properties to the prototye chain
            $A.someKey(obj, function (val, key) {
                object_public.prototype[key] = val;
            });

            // return the constructor
            return object_public;
        }
    };

    // automates ajax using pre() and post()
    // built out as needed for arcmarks.com
    $P.machine = function (obj) {

        // make a pipe and pull the animation element
        var pipe = $A.makePipe(obj),
            data_send,
            ajax_type,
            wait_animation = document.getElementById('wait_animation'),

            // use let when ES6 and move to appropriate block
            form_data,
            message;
        if ($R.Classes[pipe.model] && $R.Classes[pipe.model].hasOwnProperty("pre")) {
            // start the timer
            $R.time('start');

            // run pre() and get pipe
            pipe = $R.Classes[pipe.model].pre(pipe);

            // time it took pre() to run
            $R.time('middle');
            $A.Reg.set('pipe_pre', pipe);
        } else {

            // pre() is required to run ajax
            return;
        }

        // final block, pre() must return true to continue
        if (pipe.state === true) {

            // special form data ajax request
            // do you need to use ecode URI?
            if (pipe.form_data) {
                form_data = pipe.form_data;
                ajax_type = 'multi';
                delete pipe.form_data;
                form_data.append("pipe", JSON.stringify(pipe));
                data_send = form_data;

            // turn the object literal into a string an encode it
            } else {
                ajax_type = 'post';
                data_send = 'pipe=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(pipe));
            }

            // start the animation so the user knows ajax is going
            if (wait_animation) {
                wait_animation.style.opacity = 1;
            }

            // run ajax
            $A.ajax({
                type:     ajax_type,
                url:      $A.Reg.get('path') + $A.Reg.get('path_ajax'),
                data:     data_send,
                callback: function (pipe_string_receive) {
                    var pass_prefix = pipe_string_receive.slice(0, 3),
                        times;

                    // turn off ajax animation
                    if (wait_animation) {
                        wait_animation.style.opacity = 0;
                    }

                    // if the server want to talk it will prefix its message with |D|, and continue
                    // normal comms with an |A|
                    if (pass_prefix === '|D|') {
                        message = pipe_string_receive.match(/^(\|D\|)([\s\S]*)(\|A\|)/);
                        $A.log('|D|FROM SERVER|');
                        $A.log(message[2]);

                        // remove the debug message
                        pipe_string_receive = pipe_string_receive.slice((message[1] + message[2]).length);

                        // this should always be an |A|, update
                        pass_prefix = pipe_string_receive.slice(0, 3);
                    }
                    if (pass_prefix === '|A|') {
                        $R.time('middle');
                        pipe = JSON.parse(pipe_string_receive.slice(3));

                        // if post exists run it
                        if ($R.Classes[pipe.model].hasOwnProperty("post")) {
                            pipe = $R.Classes[pipe.model].post(pipe);

                            // record timing information for pre(), transit, and post()
                            times = $R.time('finish');
                            pipe.time.pre = times[0];
                            pipe.time.transit = times[1];
                            pipe.time.post = times[2];
                            $A.Reg.set('pipe_post', pipe);
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw "<No '|A|' or '|D|'>" + pipe_string_receive;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // holds the pipe definition
    $P.definePipe = function (obj) {
        $R.packet_hold = obj;
    };

    // clones the pipe and extends any additional properties
    $P.makePipe = function (obj) {
        return $A.extend($A.clone($R.packet_hold), obj);
    };

    // module complete, add it to the global scope
    $A = $A.extendSafe($A, $P);
}());
```

**Application Code**

```
/***************************************************************************************************
**MArc uses MUserAny on the server side.
*/
    $A.klass({
        Name: 'MArc',
        S: {
            Arcmarks:            new Arcmarks()
        },
        E: {
            fm:                  '#fm'
        },
        J: {
            fm:                  '#fm'
        },
        init: function () {
            $A.machine({model: this.Name});
        },
        initJ: function () {
            var self = this;
            $A.Event.add('malleable', function () {
                self.J.fm.draggable();
                self.J.fm.draggable('enable');
            });
            $A.Event.add('malleable_not', function () {
                self.J.fm.draggable('disable');
                self.J.fm.draggable('destroy');
            });
        },
        pre: function (pipe) {
            pipe.server.smalls.h_token = '1FOO';
            pipe.state = true;
            return pipe;
        },
        post: function (pipe) {
            this.S.Arcmarks.render(pipe.server.arcmarks, this.E.fm);
            return pipe;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm polarized by this code.

I see many good practices in use here:

- you **`use strict`**, consistently indent your code and apparently lint it too;
- you **correctly use scoping** to provide encapsulation, split code in modules and don't use globals;
- **methods are small and clean**, the code is easy to read.

However, if you ask me to look at it at a more conceptual level, I would argue against using such code in production. There are several reasons for this.

Firstly, in my opinion this code violates **the principle of [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**. It doesn't **[separate concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)** quite well, mixing AJAX, some kind of a state machine, DOM interaction and a pseudo-OOP framework in one module.

It may just be me being silly, but I don't understand what this code does, after reading it fully for several times. **The individual components seem deceptively simple but I don't understand how they work together.**

The usage example you provided strikes me as rather cryptic too. It looks like a state machine (`machine` helps), but what are `S`, `E`, `J`, `fm`? Is there some asynchronous request being made (`pre` and `post`)? Is `pipe` some kind of shared state? When do machine's states change?

Finally, **I find naming to be hard to understand and confusing**. The comments don't help because they seem to assume the reader already knows the system. This may not be the case for your team members, any new hires, or maybe even for yourself a few months down the road.

A few example that could benefit from better naming:

- `$R`, `$P`, `$A`: private, public and... global? I've never seen “R” for “private” anywhere else.
- `someKey`: I'd assume it returns true if some objects in an array have a specified key. Doesn't seem to be the case. Is this actually a `forEach`?
- `packet_hold`: is it a packet that needs to be held for some time? What is a packet? Why does calling `makePipe` set this variable?
- `getDomElements`: this sounds very broad (I thought it's something like `querySelector`) but in fact it does something very specific. It *looks* like it somehow binds “classes” defined through pseudo-OOP framework to DOM elements. So these classes are akin to MVC views? Shouldn't this code belong to a base view class?
- `getLibElements`: Totally no idea what this does. The name is very vague. Even stranger, despite being called `get`, it doesn't return anything.
- `initByProperty`: Runs a method on each module? Is this something like [`invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke)?
- `pipe_string_receive`: Is this a boolean? A string?
- `makePipe`: When I first saw the “pipes” thing, I thought you're referring to Unix-like or NodeJS-like pipes. Pipe is a quite specific concept in programming, so I'm curious why you're using the same word while apparently meaning something entirely different.

To sum it up, in my opinion this code is a bit over-engineered and suffers from [premature abstraction](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureAbstraction). I don't think this abstraction will scale well as the website gets more complex.

For inspiration, I advise you to check out **[Backbone](http://backbonejs.org)** for nice ideas about **models, views, and how they interact with each other** while being separate.

Don't miss **[Backbone.Model.extend](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend)** and how it **properly sets up prototype chain**, so `instanceof` works, etc.

**Stateful views** are a really good idea—check out **[Facebook React](http://facebook.github.io/react/)** if you're interesting in taking this idea further.

What you're trying to achieve with a custom framework is usually done with a combination of Backbone and jQuery, AngularJS and jQuery, React, or other frameworks. I'd argue the abstractions they provide are more generic and modular, and you might want to take a look at them and maybe adapt some ideas for your code.

Cheers!

> An older version of this answer [was overly harsh](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1385/2634).
>
> While I stay by my opinion that I wouldn't use this code in production, I tried to give more perspective for why it is so instead of [just being mean](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1388/2634).
>
> I'm grateful to CR community for pointing out [I was wrong](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/question-removed-after-a-harsh-review#comment4150_1388).